# firebase API add analytics through service account 403 permission error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I have a service account that has successfully made calls to both firebase API and google analytics v4 admin API.

It can create analytics v4 properties through the analytics admin API, but from firebase for some reason it fails.

The reason I'm doing this through firebase is that I need to add app data streams, and that's not possible through the analytics admin API (gotta love google...)

Making the call below as in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addGoogleAnalytics) fails with:

```
// the response
code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'The caller does not have permission',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden'
    }
  ]

// the call
apiClient.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${projectNumber}:addGoogleAnalytics`,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        analyticsAccountId,
      }),
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

403 errors appears when the email account you are using doesn't have enough permission to process the action you're doing. You must be an Owner for the existing Firebase Project and have the Edit permission for the Google Analytics account, to be able to add Analytics in your project using the API.